# Unselectable features from former shapefile layer persist in file

Tags: shapefile, layers, geometry, error

I have a file to which I added a custom shapefile layer to which I added a couple polygons. I saved it, reopened it the other day on a different computer and got an error message saying that the shapefile layer could not be read. I was not able to locate the shapefile anywhere. I deleted the layer. I deleted all the other layers. But the geometry from that shapefile layer persists in my file. I cannot select the features to delete them. Nor can I turn them on or off.

How do I get rid of them?

[image: Screenshot]

On this machine:
QGIS version
3.22.1-Białowieża
QGIS code revision
663dcf8fb9
Qt version
5.15.2
Python version
3.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have accidentally added your polygons to an annotation/graphics layer.

[image]

Use the "Modify annotations" tool to select and delete them.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see no layers on the map layer. But the layer is active, so give it a try. Activate your console and type the folowing code to get the path of your layer. Browse to that filepath, close QGIS, delete all files with that name and reopen QGIS.

```
[f.source() for f in iface.mapCanvas().layers()]
```

[image]